# How do I test jQuery code with MochaJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mocha.js

I think, mocha does not recognise jQuery in the scope of my tests, because it tests plain JavaScript without a problem. I tried to require jQuery's full code in the beginning of the .js file with my tests, tried to manually define $ with
`before(function() {/* some code */})`, but I always get this `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` when I try to run my tests and there is jQuery code tested with some of them.

Any ideas of how do I fix this?

Comment: You either need to use something like jsdom or cheerio, or hit a headless browser and work that way.

Comment: I installed jsdom and required it, but then it gives me this mistake `c:\xampp\htdocs\calculator\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\validate-names.js:2
const xnv = require("xml-name-validator");
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode`

Answer (score 1):

In docs:

> Mocha runs in the browser. Every release of Mocha will have new builds
>   of ./mocha.js and ./mocha.css for use in the browser. To setup Mocha
>   for browser use all you have to do is include the script, stylesheet,
>   tell Mocha which interface you wish to use, and then run the tests. A
>   typical setup might look something like the following, where we call
>   mocha.setup('bdd') to use the BDD interface before loading the test
>   scripts, running them onload with mocha.run().

So you can include any scripts, but the first you include libs, like jQuery, then tests

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mocha Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mocha.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="expect.js"></script>
  <script src="mocha.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
  <script src="test.array.js"></script>
  <script src="test.object.js"></script>
  <script src="test.xhr.js"></script>
  <script>
    mocha.checkLeaks();
    mocha.globals(['jQuery']);
    mocha.run();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked, but now it does not like the require('assert') part in the tests (`ReferenceError: require is not defined`)... I shall debug again now... Thank you! :>

Comment: I can help if you give more details